# A method to assign the same value to all elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array with 50 elements

```
int arr[50];
```

and I want to set all elements to the same value. How can I do that?

Comment: By array do you mean `std::vector`?

Comment: Please show some code. Currently we don't know what you mean by *array* it could be `std::vector`, `std::array`, `char[50]`, etc.

Comment: `std::fill` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 22):

Whatever kind of array you are using, if it provides iterators/pointers you can use the [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) algorithm from the `<algorithm>` header.

```
// STL-like container:
std::fill(vect.begin(), vect.end(), value);

// C-style array:
std::fill(arr, arr+elementsCount, value);
```

(where `value` is the value you want to assign and `elementsCount` is the number of elements to modify)

Not that implementing such a loop by hand would be so difficult...

```
// Works for indexable containers
for(size_t i = 0; i<elementsCount; ++i)
    arr[i]=value;
```

Comment: +1 best answer regardless of what he's using as even custom array class could implement iterators and `std::fill` allows flexibility in assigning values to ranges of elements.

Answer (score 8):

Use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vect(1000, 3); // initialize with 1000 elements set to the value 3.
```

Comment: +1, but Matteo's answer is better since yours only applies to initialization.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `for` loop if you must use arrays:

```
int array[50];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    array[i] = number; // where "number" is the number you want to set all the elements to
```

or as a shortcut, use `std::fill`

```
int array[50];

std::fill(array, array + 50, number);
```

If the number you want to set all the elements to is `0`, you can do this shortcut:

```
int array[50] = { };
```

Or if you're talking about `std::vector`, there is a constructor that takes the initial size of the vector and what to set each element to:

```
vector<int> v(50, n); // where "n" is the number to set all the elements to.
```

Answer (score 0):

From C++20 `ranges` using `fill`.

```
int arr[50];
std::ranges::fill(arr, 10);
```

All 50 elements will have value 10.

Comment: this works on C style arrays? how does it know the size of the array?

Comment: Yes it does. The size is already specified for the array variable, before calling the ranges function.