# memset function in C++ not working properly

Tags: c++, memset

I tried initializing a dynamically allocated (2D?) array as all `i`s (`i>0`) using `memset`. But then , when I am printing out the values of the array, it is printing some garbage. Following is my code snippet:

```
int main() {
    int T=1, R=3, C=3;
    int **grid = new int*[R], *temp = new int[R*C];
    for (int i=0; i<R; i++)
        grid[i] = (temp+(C*i));
    for (int t=1; t<=T; t++){
        memset(temp,1,sizeof(int)*R*C);
        cout << t << ":\n";
        for (int i=0; i<R; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<C; j++)
                cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    delete [] grid;
    delete [] temp;
    return 0;
}
```

And the following is the output:

> ```
> 1:
> 16843009 16843009 16843009
> 16843009 16843009 16843009
> 16843009 16843009 16843009
> ```

But, if I try to initialize it with 0, it works fine and displays:

> ```
> 1:
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> 0 0 0
> ```

I am relatively new to learning C++. What is going wrong with the code?

---

---

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108866/is-there-memset-that-accepts-integers-larger-than-char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memset` writes to every byte not to every int in the array.

The value `16843009` in hex is `0x01010101` an int with 4 bytes each of them set to `1`.

`memset` will operate on bytes, there is no way to make it operate on integers.

Comment: Thanks! So, is there any way to initialize the array to all 1s (other than using memset OR looping through all the elements and setting them to 1)?

Comment: @Python_user yes. [A method to assign the same value to all elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8421846/995714)